# Pets/Dogs on trains from Schiphol Airport to Rotterdam and Hoek Van Holland

Tags: trains, legal, netherlands, ferries, pets

I am taking my 2 year old dog (a half Dalmatian, half English Shepherd) from Mexico to London. In order to do this I am flying to Amsterdam and from there I need to get to Hoek Van Holland to get the ferry to take me to  Harwich, UK.

Do any of you know if I can bring my big dog on the train with me from Schiphol Airport to Rotterdam and from Rotterdam to Hoek Van Holland? My intention is to tie him to my waist and I will have to undo the Kennel into the 2 halves so it doesn't take so much room. 
I think I can get a dog pass for the day... but I don't know about the Giant kennel.

Comment: Note that 31 March, **the day after tomorrow**, will see the last train from Rotterdam to Hoek van Holland.  See [RET Replacement bus services](https://www.ret.nl/home/reizen/dienstregeling/metro/replacement-bus-services-hoekse-lijn/stena-line.html).  So one needs to consider not only the NS pet policy but also the RET pet policy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [transporting pets](https://www.nsinternational.nl/en/before-you-go/transporting-pets) page details, the only normal schedule train not allowing large pets is the Eurostar which you are not taking. Don't forget to buy a 'dog' rate ticket.

Comment: Also checked with domestic train website https://www.ns.nl/producten/alleen-te-koop-via-station-of-kaartautomaat/p/dagkaart-fiets-hond. Small one in the bag are free, dog companion is free and rest is with 3,10 ticket

Comment: In addition, one needs to check the conditions [for the RET replacement bus](https://www.ret.nl/home/reizen/dienstregeling/metro/replacement-bus-services-hoekse-lijn/stena-line.html) as trains to Hoek van Holland are soon history (the last train will depart 2 days from now).

Comment: Dogs are also welcome in Dutch buses, basically the same size limits as in trains. Small free, big pay 'dog ticket' which is about half a human adult ticket. "Small means small enough to sit in a bag you carry" I have seen quite big dogs walk into the bus/train and sit down in a bag and go as 'small'.